# Stored procedure to get data from excel sheet and load to table

Tags: sql, excel, load, extract

I want to extract data from a excel workbook sheet saved onto a file location. There are month columns and related products sold value for each month in the excel file, This needs to be loaded onto a sql table that has productname and month been a unique combination. productnames are not duplicated in the excel file.[prodcutfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHIEg.gif)

Comment: 1) Separate data into distinct worksheets and remove any extra rows or columns (usually for readability).  2) Post any code you tried and where exactly you are getting struck. This will help to address the specific issue

Comment: if you are using sql developer you can
right click on table and 
select import data and then 
select the Excel sheet or csv you want to import
select the meta data accordingly and 
click import

Comment: This is the first time I am posting so not sure whether you can see the image I have uploaded of how the excel file looks and how I want the table to look.